# What is the deal with this OP weapon (110k damage with +54 billion experience) a player dropped in my game?

Tags: diablo-iii, xbox-network, xbox-one

I left my game open after giving up trying to play with my mate using Australian internet. While I was inactive, a player joined my game and dropped this weapon:

## Professional Russian's Fast Sword

- **109, 973.9 Dmg**
- +540 Damage (Rubies)
- +8, 921 - 11, 050 Damage
- +107% Attack Speed
- *Monster kills grant + 53, 674, 999, 808 experience*
- 10.35 Attacks Per Second
- Level 1

I've been all to familiar with the hacked loot common in Diablo 2 when I played on computer, but I'm playing this game on Xbox One over Xbox LIVE with mates. Still, I went from level 66 to paragon level 919 from just completing the Belial boss fight. Am I right to be suspicious, or does this sort of loot appear in the very high ends of the game?

Comment: This is not a legitimate item. You'll see these on the PS3/4 versions as well. I'm not aware of any punishment by Blizzard for using them, but I'd be careful nonetheless.

Comment: It is worth adding that, while the answers still apply, further testing proved the benefits to be coming from a hacked jewel, rather then the weapon itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Congratulations! You found the reason why nobody takes Diablo 3 on consoles seriously. (It's too easy to manipulate stats, no seasons, hacked weapons, etc...) It is stupid easy to hack items into the game with these kind of stats, your best bet is to report the player (if possible) and then destroy the item.